# Key-value storage in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, key-value

Is there a simple key-value storage in iOS/MonoTouch to persist settings between application sessions? Or do you have to build it yourself?

EDIT:

Example

```
// Some magic function that returns a storage
IKeyValueStorage storage = GetStorage();
storage.Store( "TheKey", "The value" );

var value = storage.Get("TheKey");
```

What I need is to know what mechanism to use behind this simple interface.

Thanks

// Ankmannen

Comment: Hi, my answer is still correct. You can enter and try to read any a value with any key provided at runtime.

Comment: Sweet, I'll check it out later tonight and accept the answer if it's valid (it probably is but I gotta try it first). Thanks for the time you put into this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way way would be to go with [NSUserDefaults](http://conceptdev.blogspot.de/2009/08/monotouch-settingsbundle.html). This creates a so called "plist" file (PropertyList) which is exactly what you want. The link describes, how to use it with MonoTouch.

Comment: I need to store values as well during runtime and the key is not known until runtime. I'll update the question since my intentions is a little vague.

Comment: NSUserDefaults can be used at runtime.

Comment: I got confused by the link since it refers to the settings page? I'm trying to store level results by level id and difficulty combines as a key. I don't want these values to show up on some settings page somewhere. :D